# How to integrate Python-social-auth to osqa

Tags: python-social-auth, osqa

I would like to integrate Python-social-auth to OSQA.
Do you have any idea or any suggestion to do that?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Does OSQA provide any OAuth/OpenId mechanism?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know the way to integrate with the user account in OSQA